# How to remove/add css using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using `jquery` to remove/add `CSS` when `onchange event` fires on `dropdown`. When `onchange` fires the CSS is removed and never added. My code is given below. Please let me know if there are any issues with my code.

```
(function ($) {
$("select#edit-panes-delivery-select-address").change(function() {
    $('div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone- 
 wrapper').removeAttr('top','');
    $("div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone-wrapper").attr('top', 
 '547px');
 });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) function to apply styles

Comment: please organize your code better and add the missing html that should be changed too

Comment: share your `html` code

Answer (score 0):

use .css() to change css

> $(element).css('attribute', 'value');

```
$("div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone-wrapper").css('top', '547px');
```

Comment: actuallly I have  overrite existing jquery value by using this jquery value. In that case it is not working by adding this statement

Answer (score 0):

Small example on how you can do this, use `css()` to add any style.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonResult =  JSON.parse('[{"value":"no","name":"No Selection"},{"value":"red","name":"Red"},{"value":"blue","name":"Blue"}]')
    var options ='';
    for(let i = 0 ; i <jsonResult.length; i++){
        options +=  '<option value="'+jsonResult[i].value+'">'+jsonResult[i].name+'</option>';
    }
    $('#changer').empty().append(options);
});


$('#changer').change(function(){
  var value =  $(this).val();
  switch(value){
    case 'red': 
      $('#bulb').css('background-color','#ff0000')
      break;
    case 'blue': 
      $('#bulb').css('background-color','#0000ff')
      break;
    default: 
      $('#bulb').css('background-color','#ccc'); 
      break;  
  }
})
```

```css
#bulb{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:#ccc;
border-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bulb"></div>

<select id="changer"></select>
```

Comment: The dropdown values are not static. It will be increase dynamically.  So in that situation we can't use switch case

Comment: what you mean by " It will be increase dynamically." ?

Comment: the dropdown values are from ajax call values

Comment: So I change my answer and you can see even implementing dynamically also works fine. there is no dependant between switch and change event

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     $("div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone-wrapper").addClass("top");
>     or remove class 
>     $("div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone-wrapper").removeClass("top");
> ```

```
 in style
.top {
top: 547px;
}

 or 
    $("div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone-wrapper").css("top","547px");
```